# 3D plot in python

Tags: python, plot, 3d

[image]

I have worked out a table somewhat like the one in the link. The ultimate goal for plotting is to find out if there is a seasonal change pattern for certain products in a state. I have tried to figure out a 3-D plot in python, with x-axis being product name, y-axis being month and z-axis being YR2012 and YR2013 respectively.

And another small question related to this is how could I make python know that the SALESMONTH column contains month type of data rather than plain integers.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What is "month type"?